# Incomplete degree on resume

Tags: resume

I have an incomplete degree in Computer Science. I am about 75% complete. I don't, at all, want to touch on why it is incomplete. But It is something I would be completely comfortable discussing with a prospective employer in an interview setting.

I have been working professionally as a software developer for 4 years now. I have done a great job and have great references.

But I still have this glaring "Incomplete" on my resume.

How should I display this information about the state of my degree? I am not actively enrolled and do not plan to be. Is the best option just to put...

> So and So University, BSc, Computer Science (Incomplete).

Is there any value is saying..

> So and So University, BSc, Computer Science (Incomplete).

Should I omit the listing of the degree completely?

Is there another way to spin this?

Comment: The caveat here is if you are actively taking courses to complete it. If so, then it would be reasonable to list the date of estimated completion.

Comment: Related - [List exceptional academic achievements on CV despite dropping out?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23224/list-exceptional-academic-achievements-top-grades-published-articles-awards)

Answer (score 2):

Here is where you should consider a heart to heart conversation with your past, present, and future self as to what you want to do. You are by no means unable to obtain a degree, your work experience coupled with your positive feedback indicates a high degree of professionalism and knowledge that would be attractive to an employer. Some companies however, have a hard rule regarding academic degrees.

Here was a similar question for someone in your situation.

[Would not having a degree negatively affect my chances of getting a more senior role if I already have experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98800/would-not-having-a-degree-negatively-affect-my-chances-of-getting-a-more-senior/98801#98801)

If you are literally 75% of the way there, why not take some time to finish it, even if remotely or online? This way, instead of stating having no academic progress you can claim that you anticipate to graduate at year X. The reason why you were in two different institutions was because you were always drawn to the work and was sidetracked.

It is not unethical if your intention is to complete a degree and list it as in-progress.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on my resume.  I list it as

> Coursework towards Master of Arts, Public History, University Name, City, State

Answer (score 0):

You should not list it as incomplete, you don't have the degree so it's not incomplete, it's non existent.

I suggest listing the time spent and even give the marks if they're good ones and you can prove them.

Serving burgers part time

2 years studying computer science at XX with an A average.

Senior Engineer at YY etc,.